# How to display multiple images of products in drupal

Tags: drupal, commerce

I am using Drupal commerce
Currently, i have displayed one large size product image or can display multiple same size product images.
But, I want to display multiple images of each product, one image in big size and rest in small thumbnail sizes, so that whichever is clicked becomes the big image, as is done on the following page made using drupal commerce:

https://badboy.com/products/tops/girls-t-shirts/ornate-crest-deep-v-neck

I want to do something similar.
Can someone please point me out the correct direction?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is someting very similar you described http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/1083.

Answer (score 0):

--Login to your drupal admin side
--Click on structure -> contet type -> Your content type -> manage field
--Add image field to your content type
-->Select option "Unlimited" to upload multiple images for your product